# How does Open office Autocomplete pick suggestions?

Tags: autocomplete

I'm interested it because whenever I go to type in "Egypt" it suggests "Egyptian-brokered".

I'm wondering if from that we can deduce any thing about the number of users typing in that phrase, as a percentage of mentions of Egypt?

Thanks for your time.